# how to only get the terms in the bracket using strtok

Tags: c

My input is `(2,3,4),(2,5,4)` I only want to get `2 3 4 \n 2 5 4` as my output.
can anyone help me with this?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
   char string[50] = "(2,3,4),(2,5,4)";
   // Extract the first token
   char * token = strtok(string, "()");
   // loop through the string to extract all other tokens
   while( token != NULL ) {
      printf( " %s\n", token ); //printing each token
      token = strtok(NULL, "()");
   }
   return 0;
}
``
```

Comment: If you use the non-standard `strsep()` which is re-entrant (`strtok()` is not), you can first break it into three tokens with "()" separator, and split the first and the third tokens with the "," separator.

Comment: @WeatherVane can you please answer this question

Comment: Yes, I have posted an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have implemented this with the standard `strtok()` not the non-standard `strsep()` mentioned in comment.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) {
    char input[] = "(2,3,4),(2,5,4)";
    char *tok = strtok(input, "( ,)" );
    for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        // each set
        for(int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
            // break each set
            if(tok) {
                printf("%s ", tok);   //printing each token
                tok = strtok(NULL, "( ,)" );
            }
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Program output

```
2 3 4 
2 5 4
```